# Angular: Detect particular key press when context menu open

Tags: angular, mousedown, onmousedown

In my Angular app, I have implemented a context menu, and want to trigger an event when a particular key (`up` or `down`) is pressed. I have tried placing `(keydown)="onKeydown($event)` in my outer `div`, but it doesn't detect any key presses. It *does* detect a `mouseover` event if I place `(mouseover)="onKey()"` in the same div. Does anyone know how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
import { Inject, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/fromEvent';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

export class Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

subscription: Subscription;

// and in your constructor import documnet 
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
// and in some lificicle hook or in constructor 
ngOnInit() {
 this.subscription = fromEvent(this.document, 'keydown').subscribe(event => {
     // do some thing 
  })

}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. This is successfully triggering a response, but I notice if I press a key it triggers three consecutive identical events. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: I think I know why. You need to unsubscribe from subscription when your component is destroys. let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer, I found a simpler approach that does the same thing, just adding `window.addEventListener()` in the constructor of the context menu. The problem I'm having, which also happened when I used your code, is that when I move the mouse off the context menu, key presses no longer trigger the event, even if I then move the mouse back over the menu. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @RNdev Please can you create a simple example so that I can help you?